# Confusion matrix and accuracy not in sync

Tags: python, logistic-regression, accuracy, confusion-matrix

I am getting the following result for the confusion matrix and accuracy for a logistic
regression model.

```
array([[26,  0,  0],
       [ 1, 24,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 24]])
Accuracy: 1.0
```

Is this a correct result? As a 1 in the second row indicates that the actual
value was different from the predicted one. But that means accuracy can't be 1.0.
But still python returned the accuracy as 1.0

The code used to calculate this is :

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score 
accuracy_score(y_true=y_train, y_pred=classifier.predict(X_train))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your accuracy is rounded to one decimal:

```
acc = (26 + 24 + 24) / (1 + 26 + 24 + 24)
```

results in `0.9866666666666667` but

```
np.round(acc, 1)
```

gives `1.0`.